# transform: scale() firefox text issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transforms

I want to use css-transforms to scale a text on hover to another size. It works very well in all browsers (even IE!), but firefox has a strange problem with the font. The animation + scale works but the text in the scaled element becomes a bit unsharp and then after a few milliseconds it becomes sharp again.

I made a simple [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwVZoM) where you can reproduce it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scale">
        Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero. And most times they're friends, like you and me! I should've known way back when... You know why, David? Because of the kids. They called me Mr Glass.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

div.scale {
    transition: 0.1s linear;
}

div.scale:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Any help would be cool!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried scaling it to 2 and it works. It seems there is a issue when scaling with numbers which have fractional digits. I'm going to report this bug to the mozilla team.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by adding `translateZ(0)` the blurry effect disappears.

```
div.scale:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5) translateZ(0);
}
```

This way it forces a 2D transform.